# Insert into select combine with PHP code

Tags: php, sql

Hi guys I having some difficulties interacting with php code so I can execute the statement written in sql form i can't bind the other variables because im also doing some insert into select in just one statement can you help me out? thanks a lot in advance .

What im trying to do in this code is when a user is trying to sign up there username and password will be inserted into the account_table and at the same time the customer_IDno will be also fetch to be inserted in account_table to be a foreign key, I already got the statement but the problem is I don't know how to interact with the php code with these kind of statement here's the code for the SQL. hope you'll help thanks a lot

```
INSERT INTO customer_table 
(customer_firstname , customer_middlename , customer_lastname ,
customer_email , customer_address , customer_contact)
VALUES ('Adrian','Manuel','Abrasaldo','Email','New York',09254872645);

INSERT INTO account_table(
account_username , account_password , customer_IDno) 
SELECT '$username' , '$password' , customer_IDno
FROM customer_table WHERE customer_email = '$email')
```

Comment: you are first inserting into customer_table and then inserting into account table right.

Comment: yes that's what im doing in that statement customer_id will be fetch from customer_table after the user sign up then the username and password will be inserted with the customer_IDno at the same time but im having difficulties with the php code

Comment: $username and password field is not present in customer_table then  it can not be selected from the table ,It will be a $_POST values

Comment: yes exactly i have already tried that in phpmyadmin and it works very well my only problem is how to interact with php code because it has select inside the insert into

Comment: there is no need to select in when inserting to account table $suername and $password can be get from $_POST and customer_id can be get from as last_insert_id when inserting is made to customer table . So this way we have alll . now insert into the account  table

Comment: you have a point i get what you said thanks

Comment: I update my answer do neccessary changes as per requirement

Answer (score 1):

**Something like This Code :**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO customer_table (customer_firstname ,customer_middlename, 
        customer_lastname , customer_email , customer_address ,
        customer_contact) VALUES ('Adrian','Manuel','Abrasaldo','Email','New York',09254872645)";

        mysqli_query($con, $sql);

       //this sql will generate the id .Save it to the variable Here :$newCustID

       $newCustID = mysqli_insert_id($con); // can be get easily
       if ($newCustID) {
          $customer_IDno = $newCustID;
       }


       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];

       $account_sql = "INSERT INTO account_table(account_username , account_password , 
           customer_IDno) VALUES( ".$username." , ".$password." , ".$customer_IDno.")";
       mysqli_query($con, $account_sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

First execute this query

```
mysqli_query(INSERT INTO customer_table 
(customer_firstname , customer_middlename , customer_lastname ,
customer_email , customer_address , customer_contact)
VALUES ('Adrian','Manuel','Abrasaldo','Email','New York',09254872645),$conn);
```

then use

`$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // $conn is your connection string`

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

  $account_sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO account_table(account_username, account_password,customer_IDno) VALUES( ".$username." , ".$password." , ".$id.")",$conn);
```